# Какой аргумент просит функция в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Ребят, я сделал код ниже, запустил его. Но выдаёт ошибку в 14 строке:

> TypeError: Main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Сам код:

```
from random import randint as rndigit

class Program:
    def Main(self):
        procent_chance = int(input("Введите шанс: "))
        self.Calculate(procent_chance)
    def Calculate(self, procent_chance):
        now_chance = rndigit(0, 100)
        if now_chance == procent_chance or now_chance <= procent_chance:
            return (f"Вам повезло с шансом: {now_chance}")
    return (f"Вам не повезло с шансом: {now_chance}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Program.Main()

input()
```

Скажите пожалуйста что делать, чтобы программа работала.

Comment: `Program().Main()` - после `Program` нужно добать скобки, чтбы создать экземпляр класса, а потом уже вызывать у него метод. Кстати, функции в питоне принято называть маленькими буквами.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint as rndigit

class Program:
    def main(self):
        procent_chance = int(input("Введите шанс: "))
        result = self.calculate(procent_chance)
        return result

    def calculate(self, procent_chance):
        now_chance = rndigit(0, 100)
        if now_chance == procent_chance or now_chance <= procent_chance:
            return f"Вам повезло с шансом: {now_chance}"
        return f"Вам не повезло с шансом: {now_chance}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
#    Program.Main()
    program = Program()
    print(program.main())

input()
```

Comment: Так в чём моя проблема или ошибка?

Comment: @Mr_CatYT нужно создать экземпляр класса `program = Program()`, а затем вызвать метод `main`

Comment: Пишет:  `<__main__.Program object at 0x000002A01F436D48>`
Сделал как вы, выдаёт при запуске программы.

Comment: @Mr_CatYT скопируйте весь мой пример и запустите, т.к. у вас еще были ошибки